# Feistel Network-why right halves is kept unchanged in feistel Network?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

As I'm going through feistel network in DES algorithm.

While encryption uses feistel Network , the input block divided into two halves left and right half.
In each round , R half goes through unchanged.But L part goes through an operation.

I didn't understood why right halves is kept unchanged in feistel Network?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @dbush sorry i didn't knew that.

Comment: When you ask this question over on [crypto.se], please delete it here. Be sure to check out if similar questions are already answered there.

Comment: I don't see it there yet, so feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need the right half unchanged so you can later decrypt the cyphertext.  Have a look at how you could decrypt a Feistel cipher if both halves were modified by the F function.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the function used to operate on half of the bits need not be reversible that the same operation can be used to perform and undo itself.

Most ciphers require that every transformation of the plaintext performed in encryption to be reversible so that they can be undone during decryption.

Since this is not a requirement for ciphers using the Feistel structure, it opens up new possibilities for the round functions.For detailed description on Feistel Cipher, please refer the Feistel Cipher blogspot [here](https://stepuptocrypt.blogspot.com/2019/02/feistel-cipher.html).